# C - floating point rounding on small numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding-error

Running this piece of code on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790, I get strange results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CALCULUS 2052 - 1.0 - margin
void main(void)
{
    float margin = 1.0001;
    float a = CALCULUS;
    printf("%2.6f\t%2.6f\n", a, CALCULUS);
}
```

I have

```
$ gcc test2.c && ./a.out
2050.000000 2049.999900
```

Can someone explain this behavior?
I know it doesn't occur when I use `double` instead of `float` but I find it surprising the rounding occurs at such a small number.

Comment: How many significant decimal digits do you exoect from `float` and why?

Comment: FWIW, `main()` returns `int`, not `void`. Your compiler will warn you about that kind of thing if you turn up the warnings.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' FWIW, A C compliant compiler may allow `void main(void)` and not warn even with warnings turned up.  "... or in some other implementation-defined manner" C11 5.1.2.2.1 1

Comment: @chux: The OP's compiler will warn about `void main(void)` if he turns up the warnings.

Answer (score 5):

With

```
float a = CALCULUS;
```

the value stored in `a` is of course a 32-bit single precision floating point value. The result of the `CALCULUS` expansion is converted from a `double` to a `float` in the initialization of `a`.

But when you pass the expansion of `CALCULUS` directly to `printf` it is a `double` value that is passed.

In short, the result of `2052 - 1.0 - margin` is a *`double`*.

Comment: is it because 1.0 is a `double` that the entire expression is a `double` ?

Comment: @Jav Yes that's correct. If you used `1.0f` it would be of type `float` instead.

Comment: maybe you could update your answer with this remark. Thanks !